# TWRP fails to decrypt data on OnePlus One

Tags: twrp, oneplus-one

During charging my OnePlus One turned off and I wasn't able to turn the phone back on by pressing the power button. I wasn't able to get the phone to recharge. I managed to boot to recovery (`power + volume down`). Now TWRP fails to decrypt with the current, correct password and can't be used in any way. I have rebooted several times, considering doing a factory reset.

TWRP error I get:

```
E: Unable to mount storage. 
Full SELinux support is present. 
E: Failed to decrypt data.
```

---

Latest TWRP and a recent CM 13 nightly ROM installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen due to many reasons ! A common issue is the fail in the boot order sequence which indeed is stored correctly in the TWRP from which you booted into.  Now, Are you able to boot through the normal method ?  . If not, then boot to bootloader and select the normal startup option. Try fixing permissions from TWRP and see if it fixes the problem.  Good Luck!

Comment: Good to know your problem is solved.

Comment: Not solved. From what I've understood there's a bug in OPO software that causes issues with TWRP. I currently can't use TWRP at all, only boot and I'm not sure if even a factory reset would fix the issue.

TWRP error message I get:
`E: Unable to mount storage.  
Full SELinux support is present.  
E: Failed to decrypt data.`

Comment: Booting via bootloader solved the issue.