# OnePlus One bootloop, not related to flashing

Tags: boot-loop, oneplus-one

My phone entered bootloop during charging, restarting doesn't solve the issue and I can't boot to bootloader, only "fastboot mode" text is stuck on screen. TWRP recovery can be accessed and I've tried clearing cache & Dalvik cache. I haven't flashed nor installed anything in months (CyanogenMod 14 installed), the phone has only been used for calling and messaging since late 2016. I've also had [a similar issue before](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/151131/twrp-fails-to-decrypt-data-on-oneplus-one), happened during charging as well.

I found a potential fix by Ricardo Cerqueira of Cyanogen Inc., shared by [Android Police](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/10/13/heres-easy-fix-oneplus-one-sudden-death-bug-results-neverending-boot-loops/):

> While your phone is booted to TWRP, run these commands on your
>   computer:
>
> ```
> adb shell
> make_ext4fs /dev/block/mmcblk0p15
> ```
>
> Here's the output of the command:
>
> ```
> make_ext4fs /dev/block/mmcblk0p15
> Creating filesystem with parameters:
>     Size: 33554432
>     Block size: 4096
>     Blocks per group: 32768
>     Inodes per group: 2048
>     Inode size: 256
>     Journal blocks: 1024
>     Label:
>     Blocks: 8192
>     Block groups: 1
>     Reserved block group size: 7
> Created filesystem with 11/2048 inodes and 1166/8192 blocks
> ```
>
> Once everything is over, the OnePlus One should be restored without
>   any data loss.

I get identical output when running the commands, but the phone is still persistently in bootloop.

When reflashing my ROM the installation fails. The installation processes finishes far faster than normally (around 10 seconds) and this error is displayed twice in TWRP log (in red):

```
E:unknown command [log]
E:unknown command [log]
```

What should I try and is the cause of this issue now known?

---

complete Windows PowerShell output, commands in bold:

**`PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> adb shell`**

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
```

**`~ # make_ext4fs /dev/block/mmcblk0p15`**

```
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 33554432
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 2048
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label:
    Blocks: 8192
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/2048 inodes and 1166/8192 blocks
```