# How to wipe OS partition in TWRP?

Tags: twrp, partitions

Operating system partition can be wiped in order to reinstall a [broken ROM installation](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/171989/oneplus-one-bootloop-not-related-to-flashing) for example, personal files will be left intact. What is the correct [partition](https://twrp.me/faq/whattowipe.html) to wipe?
Partitions for OnePlus One in TWRP (excluding cache and USB OTG):

- system
- data
- internal storage

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Let’s start with a list of standard internal memory partitions on
>   Android phones and tablets. These are:
>
> ```
> /boot
> /system
> /recovery
> /data
> /cache
> /misc
> ```
>
> In addition, there are the SD card partitions.
>
> ```
> /sdcard
> /sd-ext
> ```
>
> Note that only /sdcard is found in all Android devices and the rest
>   are present only in selected devices.
>
> Let’s now take a look at the purpose and contents of each of these
>   partitions.
>
> `/boot`
>
> This is the partition that enables the phone to boot, as the name
>   suggests. It includes the kernel and the ramdisk. Without this
>   partition, the device will simply not be able to boot. Wiping this
>   partition from recovery should only be done if absolutely required and
>   once done, the device must NOT be rebooted before installing a new
>   one, which can be done by installing a ROM that includes a /boot
>   partition.
>
> `/system`
>
> This partition basically contains the entire operating system, other
>   than the kernel and the ramdisk. This includes the Android user
>   interface as well as all the system applications that come
>   pre-installed on the device. Wiping this partition will remove Android
>   from the device without rendering it unbootable, and you will still be
>   able to put the phone into recovery or bootloader mode to install a
>   new ROM.
>
> `/recovery`
>
> The recovery partition can be considered as an alternative boot
>   partition that lets you boot the device into a recovery console for
>   performing advanced recovery and maintenance operations on it.
>   Example:Clockwork Mod, TWRP etc.
>
> `/data`
>
> Also called user data, the data partition contains the user’s data –
>   this is where your contacts, messages, settings and apps that you have
>   installed go. Wiping this partition essentially performs a factory
>   reset on your device, restoring it to the way it was when you first
>   booted it, or the way it was after the last official or custom ROM
>   installation. When you perform a wipe data/factory reset from
>   recovery, it is this partition that you are wiping.
>
> `/cache`
>
> This is the partition where Android stores frequently accessed data
>   and app components. Wiping the cache doesn’t effect your personal data
>   but simply gets rid of the existing data there, which gets
>   automatically rebuilt as you continue using the device.
>
> `/misc`
>
> This partition contains miscellaneous system settings in form of
>   on/off switches. These settings may include CID (Carrier or Region
>   ID), USB configuration and certain hardware settings etc. This is an
>   important partition and if it is corrupt or missing, several of the
>   device’s features will not function normally.
>
> `/sdcard`
>
> This is not a partition on the internal memory of the device but
>   rather the SD card. In terms of usage, this is your storage space to
>   use as you see fit, to store your media, documents, ROMs etc. on it.
>   Wiping it is perfectly safe as long as you backup all the data you
>   require from it, to your computer first. Though several user-installed
>   apps save their data and settings on the SD card and wiping this
>   partition will make you lose all that data.
>
> On devices with both an internal and an external SD card – devices
>   like the Samsung Galaxy S and several tablets – the /sdcard partition
>   is always used to refer to the internal SD card. For the external SD
>   card – if present – an alternative partition is used, which differs
>   from device to device. In case of Samsung Galaxy S series devices, it
>   is /sdcard/sd while in many other devices, it is /sdcard2. Unlike
>   /sdcard, no system or app data whatsoever is stored automatically on
>   this external SD card and everything present on it has been added
>   there by the user. You can safely wipe it after backing up any data
>   from it that you need to save.
>
> `/sd-ext`
>
> This is not a standard Android partition, but has become popular in
>   the custom ROM scene. It is basically an additional partition on your
>   SD card that acts as the /data partition when used with certain ROMs
>   that have special features called APP2SD+ or data2ext enabled. It is
>   especially useful on devices with little internal memory allotted to
>   the /data partition. Thus, users who want to install more programs
>   than the internal memory allows can make this partition and use it
>   with a custom ROM that supports this feature, to get additional
>   storage for installing their apps. Wiping this partition is
>   essentially the same as wiping the /data partition – you lose your
>   contacts, SMS, market apps and settings.

[Source](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/android-partitions-explained-boot-system-recovery-data-cache-misc/)

Note: Wiping /system means removing the android installation(ROM), and /data removes all apps (app+data), wiping internal storage means deletes every thing. If you want to install ROM only by wiping /system, then, the new ROM should be with same android version as that of old. Otherwise, it will crash.

Comment: I'm confused by the boot partition. Are you saying that wiping boot will brick the device? Does TWRP even allow wiping the partition?

Comment: TWRP allows wiping cache, Dalvik cache, System, Data and Internal Storage. If you backup using TWRP, it will stores /boot, /system, /data (you can see their file sizes, while checking checkboxes). This helps you to return to current ROM, if anything happens in between. I recommend a backup before any operations.

Answer (score 0):

You should go for advanced wipe and choose:
-DalviK/ART Cache
-System
-Data
-Cache
And don`t format:
-Internal Memory
-Sdcard